# Create a Column with list value from columns that start with a substring from a dataframe, for each rows

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions, aggregation

I have a dataframe like this:

`name, surname, delivery_?, delivery_?, delivery_?,other delivery_?, recovery_?,recovery_?, recovery_?, and other recovery_?`

I want:

`name, surname, delivery, recovery`

where delivery column as for values `[df['delivery_?'],df['delivery_?'],df['delivery_?'],........]` (list) for each row,

and recovery column as for values `[df['recovery_?'],df['recovery_?'],df['recovery_?'],....]` (list) for each row.

i know that in parent_list i have ['recovery','delivery', ....]

I use python.
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create array columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

parent_list = ['recovery', 'delivery']

df2 = df.select(
    *[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if not reduce(lambda a, b: a or c.startswith(b), parent_list, False)],
    *[F.array(*[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if c.startswith(i)]).alias(i) for i in parent_list]
)
```

Comment: ok thanks but in real i have many fields name, surname ....... and  i dont know name of fields delivery_A, delivery_B, delivery_C how i take dinamically this job?

Comment: i know only that start for delivery or replace

Comment: i have parent_list with list of string ['recovery','delivery',...]